# Difference between providers of Component decorator and NgModule decorator in Angular 2

Tags: angular

**providers array of Component decorator**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector:    'hero-list',
    templateUrl: './hero-list.component.html',
    providers:  [ HeroService ]
 })
 export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
    /* . . . */
 }
```

**providers array of NgModule decorator**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  providers:    [ Logger ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  exports:      [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

What is difference between these two providers array in Angular2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is the scope where a provider is available and how many instances will be created.

**instance per provider**

If you add it to a component, every instance of this component will have it's own instance of the services, while for non-lazy-loaded modules there will only be a single instance for the whole application.

**scope**

If you add it to a component, only the component and directives applied to it, and the descendants of this component will be able to inject an instance.

**hierarchical injection and provider lookup**

When a component injects a service, DI looks it up by checking the components providers, then its parent, and further ancestors until it finds a matching provider. If it can't find one when the root component (`AppComponent`) is reached it looks at the applications root scope (`@NgModule()`).

**lazy loaded modules**

Lazy loaded modules have their own "root" scope. This was introduced because providers of an injector can't be modified once initialized and lazy modules are not available initially.
Therefore providers of lazy loaded modules won't become available globally, only within the scope of the lazy loaded module.
To work around this limitation `forRoot()` was introduced (mostly a convention instead of some feature) to register providers in the root scoope while keeping the rest of the imported module lazy.

Comment: Does lazy-loaded modules have the its own instances of services that were provided in app module or they (the services) are injected as singletons even for lazy modules?

Comment: Services provided in AppModule are global singletons for lazy or non-lazy loaded code. Serviced provided in a lazy loaded module are only available to this lazy loaded module (and everything else the lazy module drags in). If a service is provided in AppModule **and** a lazy module, then there are 2 instances and the provider in the lazy module shadows the provider in AppModule for the lazy module itself (and everything else the lazy module drags in), but everything else gets the instance provided in AppModule.