# Class's Set throws Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature using BehaviorSubject and Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

as stated in the title, I'm getting the following error when trying to set a new `Item`:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'ItemModel' has no compatible call signatures.

I'm using `BehaviorSubject` and `Subject` to share a set `Item` between two different states. Essentially, I want to set a chosen `Item` and then, when going to its details page, get it.

Here's my `item.model.ts`, let's suppose it has only an `id` property:

```
export class ItemModel {
    public id: string;
    constructor( id: string ) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Here's my `item.service.ts` use to `get` and `set` an `Item`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { ItemModel } from './item.model';

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {

    public _item = new BehaviorSubject<ItemModel>(null);
    item$ = this._item.asObservable();

    public set item(item: ItemModel) {
        this._item.next(item);
    }

    public get item() : ItemModel {
        return this._item.getValue();
    }

}
```

My `item.component.ts` would set a given `Item`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ItemService } from '../item.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-item',
    templateUrl: './item.html',
    styleUrls: ['./item.scss'],
    providers: [ItemService]
})

export class ItemComponent {

    constructor(private _router: Router, private _itemService : ItemService) { }

    goToDetails(item : ItemModel){
       this._itemService.item(item); //Throws the error
       this._router.navigate(['/details', item.id]);
    }

}
```

And on `details.page.ts` I want to get that `Item`:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
 import { ItemService } from './item.service';
 import { ItemModel } from './item.model';

 @Component({
     selector: 'app-details-page',
     templateUrl: './details.page.html',
     styleUrls: ['./details.page.scss'],
     providers: [ItemService]
 })

 export class DetailsPage {

     private _item = ItemModel;
     private subscription : Subscription;

     constructor( private _itemService: ItemService ) { }

     ngOnInit() {

         this.subscription = this._itemService.item$
             .subscribe(item => console.log(item));

     }

 }
```

What I tried so far on the invocation of the setter:

- `item as ItemModel`
- `item as typeof ItemModel`
- Other solutions coming from [this answer by @Sefe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42487130/4684539) and many more
- Checking a lot of issues opened on Typescript's GitHub Issues [like this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7960)

**What Am I doing wrong? How can I make sure that ItemModel has a compatible signature?**

**EDIT**

With @n00dl3 's help I was able to get rid of this error. But, unluckily, when logging inside `details.page.ts`'s `ngOnInit` I get `null`. When I log inside the setter it shows the correct output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itemService.item` is a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) so you should not call it like a function, but like a property :

```
this._itemService.item = item;
```

[from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) :

> Defining a setter on new objects in object initializers This will
>   define a pseudo-property current of object language that, when
>   assigned a value, will update log with that value:
>
> ```
> var language = {
>   set current(name) {
>     this.log.push(name);
>   },
>   log: []
> }
>
> language.current = 'EN';
> console.log(language.log); // ['EN']
>
> language.current = 'FA';
> console.log(language.log); // ['EN', 'FA']
> ```

For your null vs item problem :

It is because you should not declare your service inside component, but inside an `NgModule` (so you **should remove it from your components providers**):

```
@NgModule({
  imports:[CommonModule],
  declarations:[SomeComponent],
  providers:[ItemService]
})
export class myModule{}
```

when you declare a service inside component's providers, it is only available to that component, dirrectives applied to it and its children. (More details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300551/difference-between-providers-of-component-decorator-and-ngmodule-decorator-in-an).) So it means you are currently not talking to the same service instance in `DetailsPage` and in `ItemComponent`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I was trying this solution few minutes ago. `console.log(this._item.getValue());` on the setter shows me a fine Item, but, the log on DetailsPage's `ngOnInit` gives me `null`. Any idea?

Comment: Because the default value for your `BehaviorSubject` is `null` and the setter has not been called yet when you `console.log(item)` inside DetailsPage...

Comment: Uhm, I'm calling the setter inside `item.component.ts` before `navigating` to `details.page.ts`.

Comment: Ow, that's because you should declare your service inside a module, not inside component: `@NgModule(... providers:[MyService]...)` module providers are application-wide while components providers are component+children wide...

Comment: Do you mean, supposing I have a `pages.module.ts` that declares and exports `ItemComponent` and `DetailsPage` I should inject `ItemService` into its `providers`? If so the problem persists.`

Comment: I don't know how is structured your application, but you should declare it inside the module, yes. If the problem persists, that's because you still declare it inside your components.