# How does forRoot pattern ensure singletons for entire app?

Tags: angular

Neither reading the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#forroot), nor learning the source code of [Angular's metadata resolver](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.x/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L507) make me sense of how actually does Angular deal with `forRoot` pattern when a module imports other one.

For now I understand the following things related with the issue:

- the purpose of using `forRoot` pattern is add singleton providers/services in app
- when a module (for e.g. AppModule) imports some other one its providers are aviable for entire app ([doc](https://angular.io/guide/providers#provider-scope))
- when the module provides both providers and declarations we need to import it in different modules, not only in the app one
- when such importing happens in lazy-loaded modules this causes to there are new instances of the providers in app (not singletons as expected) (@Günter Zöchbauer's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300551/difference-between-providers-of-component-decorator-and-ngmodule-decorator-in-an/42300610?noredirect=1#comment84545502_42300610))

Well, for my vision to ensure providers as singletons we need refactor the target module with both providers and declarations so that its decalrations were **removed** from @NgModule to ModuleWithProviders.providers. So when a lazy-loaded module imports this module new instances of its providers is not initialized.

But the [example of code](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qodrmmjreyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcore%2Fcore.module.ts) in the docs breaks down my vision on it. There is the providers array in @NgModule of the not-app module.

The question is why as the module is imported both in app and a lazy-loaded modules Angular initialize dublicates of its providers, but when there is `forRoot` pattern such behavior does not happen? What's the difference (for **lazy-loaded** module) of importing module which has static implementation of `forRoot` pattern and which has not?

Comment: Hi @Mergasov, could you clarify the second part of your question? "What's the difference (for lazy-loaded module) of importing module which has static implementation of forRoot pattern and which has not?"