# Difference between Testbed.inject(serviceName) and fixture.debugElement.injector.get(serviceName) in Angular Unit Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I was going through the test cases written by my team members. What I observed was at some places they've used **TestBed.inject(serviceName)** for injecting the service and at some places they've used **fixture.debugElement.injector.get(serviceName)**. Can somebody tell me the difference between these two? Also what is the correct way of injecting services?

For eg:

let abc: ABCService

Technique 1: abc = TestBed.inject(ABCService)
Technique 2: abc = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ABCSerice)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8):

I think they are essentially the same thing. I only use `Technique 1`.

In older versions of Angular, it was `TestBed.get` but now it is `TestBed.inject`.

I think `TestBed.inject` gets the service from the root injector while `fixture.debugElement.injector.get` gets the service that is actually injected into the component.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.cnblogs.com/Answer1215/p/7647351.html).

You can provider a service in the `Component` decorator of a `Component` and each instance of this service will be unique (a separate instance) and I bet `fixture.debugElement.inject.get` will get this unique instance provided in the decorator as opposed to the global singleton. Check out providers in decorators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300551/difference-between-providers-of-component-decorator-and-ngmodule-decorator-in-an).

Comment: The last sentence is important. You actually **need to use `fixture.debugElement.inject.get`** instead of `TestBed.inject` if you have component-specific services etc. (i.e. that are being provided in the component). Otherwise you get the wrong element in your tests, which is painful to debug, as your implementation and your test work on different instances and you may not easily get what is what.